# Mysqli SELECT FROM WHERE IF

Tags: php, mysqli

```
public function checkIfItemLeft($itemNameSecond){
        $query = "SELECT itemLeft 
                  FROM items
                  WHERE itemName = '$itemNameSecond' 
                  AND itemLeft > 0 Limit 1";
        if(mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query)) {
            return true;
        }
        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return false;
    }
```

How do I check if `itemLeft` is greater than 0?

Comment: `itemLeft > 0` looks good. What's wrong with it? Error? Share it. Share everything.

Comment: it returns false. But in my database itemLeft is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query could also be done like

```
$query="SELECT CASE WHEN itemLeft>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        FROM items 
        WHERE itemName = '$itemNameSecond'";
$result=mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
if ($result) {  // the condition is necessary in case not record exists ...
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  $largerthan0 = $row[0];  // will contain 1 if the value was >0
} 
else {
  $largerthan0 = 0;
}
```

Just thought of a shorter alternative:

```
public function checkIfItemLeft($itemNameSecond){
 $query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items 
         WHERE itemName = '$itemNameSecond' AND itemLeft>0";
 $result=mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 return ($row[0]>0);
}
```